# непонятный баг с кодировкой

Tags: php, html, utf-8

есть текст который достается из бд (там кодировка utf mb 64 general ci) так вот если там есть 2 спец символа "//текст//" то идет перевод в `<em>текст</em>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но почему то такой текст иногда показывает вопросительный знак, при чем если убрать хтмл тэг em все становится нормально, и я вообще не представляю что это такое, спасибо

Comment: Добавьте скин где у вас кодировка к таблице указана, пожалуйста.

Comment: И перевод какой функцией осуществляете? Если такая ситуация только во время перевода то либо до перевода текст в нужную кодировку переводить, либо смотреть вообще функция поддерживает эту исходную кодировку в БД. И я так и не понял какая у вас кодировка: utf8mb4?

Comment: Вы такую кодировку из-за Emoji выбрали? Подключение к БД правильную кодировку указываете `utf8mb4`?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, твой код, делающий обёртывание, отрезает часть байтов от многобайтного символа. Не удалось показать на ideone, но [примерно так](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/704114/178988).